# Bootstrap DateTimePicker not opening picker on correct date

Tags: datetimepicker

When I'm editing an existing record and open the Bootstrap DateTimePicker it shows today's date, instead of the input value date. When I close the calender (without changing the date) and reopen it again, it DOES show the month of the record value.

Can someone tell me how to initially get it to open on the right date?

HTML:

```html
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="07-09-2017">
  <span class="input-group-addon" for="Date">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

JavaScript DateTimePicker:

```js
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'nl',
    debug: false,
    useCurrent: false,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    allowInputToggle: true,
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce using lastest version (4.17.45) of [eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Which datetimepicker are you using? Which version? Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: I'm not understanding the close vote here for lacking an mcve, it contains a clear MCVE, problem statement, etc. The only thing missing that I can see is a version number, but that doesn't seem like a reason to close the question... especially when it has received an answer detailing which version this bug shows up in and which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue in version 4.7.14, but this works fine in latest version 4.17.47